# i am trying to upload nextjs project but

Tags: next.js, cpanel

after uploading my files on my domain enter domain browsers it is showing me files only

want to upload the next js project to Cpanel
i also created a node js server but in next js I can not find any files apps or server js like that

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

NextJS needs to be started on the server side before it will properly serve assets. It sounds like you are just hosting static assets which will not work.

[Running NextJS in production](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-cli#production)